# Buildfire CLI issue with running command lines

Tags: buildfire

I'm having an issue with using the Buildfire CLI commands for starting a new project. I am able to start the CLI and `buildfire init` but I'm not able to update the SDK with `buildfire update` or start up a React or Angular project with `buildfire run <pluginName>`.

Buildfire is installed globally.

The error provided is "Please run this command inside the SDK's folder" but I'm running each command within the "BuildfireSDK" folder.

Is there a file structure to follow in order to run command lines?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the **buildfire run** command, the third parameter is optional and it's not the plugin name. (It's actually the port number.) You should be able to run the tester just specifying **buildfire run**.

For the **buildfire update** command, are you running it in the root **BuildfireSDK** folder? I tried it just now on my own machine and it worked without issue. (You will see that message if you run the command in a subfolder of BuildfireSDK.)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am running each command the the very top of BuildfireSDK folder. I uninstalled and reinstalled the npm package. Same issue. Using version buildfire-cli version 1.01.

Comment: @sparkyspub What happens when you run the command "buildfire run" (without any additional parameters)?

Comment: I get the Buildfire logo and then error: Please run this command inside the SDK's folder. I'm running the command at the top of BuildfireSDK folder. I have the People plugin within the plugins folder

Comment: @sparkyspub I'm having a hard time visualizing what you're describing... would it be possible to provide a screen shot?

Comment: Version 1.0.2 fixed my issue. Everything working now. Thanks!